# tmpfiles.d logs on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, tmpfs

I'm having trouble with a conf file that resides in `/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/`
(directory is not created on boot)

I'm trying to figure out what is wrong. But can't seem to find any indication for that in the system log files (syslog, dmesg)
Is there a specific place that log actions of `tmpfiles.d` process?

(Ubuntu 14.04.2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [man page of tmpfiles.d](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/tmpfiles.d.html)

> systemd-tmpfiles uses the configuration files from the above directories to describe the creation, cleaning and removal of volatile and temporary files and directories which usually reside in directories such as /run or /tmp.

Since [Ubuntu 14.04 is not using systemd](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers), this directory is of no relevance to you.

Comment: Thanks. I wonder why I have a bunch of files in `/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d` that made me chase the wind (postgresql.conf, sshd.conf)

Comment: Unless you installed some packages which were not meant for your system, this could be there just in preparation for a future update.